# sql - How do I implement a table where few attributes are just references to another tuple?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-adf

I have a Sql table, shown below:-

```
> select * from table1;
    |--------------------------------------------------|
    | ID | A1 | A2 | B1 | B2 | C1 | C2 | REF_B | REF_C |
    |--------------------------------------------------|
    | 1  | a1 | a1 | b1 | b1|  c1 | c1 |  1    |   1   |
    | 2  | a2 | a2 | b2 | b2|  c1 | c1 |  2    |   1   |
    | 3  | a3 | a3 | b1 | b1|  c1 | c1 |  1    |   1   |
    |--------------------------------------------------|
```

- `ID` is Primary key.
- `A1` and `A2` are unique to each tuple.
- `B1` and `B2` are the values of tuple pointed to by `REF_B` attribute of the current row.
- `C1` and `C2` are the values of tuple pointed to by `REF_C` attribute of the current row.
- `REF_B` refers to the `ID` of another tuple in this same table from where we should get the values of `Bx`.
- `REF_C` refers to the `ID` of another tuple in this same table from where we should get the values of `Cx`.

In this the above approach the obvious problem we face is propagating the changes made in tuple `1` to tuples `2` and `3`. Right now we have used programmatic approach (Java code) to achieve this.

*This is both difficult and not beautiful.*

### Proposed change

Divide `table1` into three tables.

```
> select * from table1_a;
    |------------------------------|
    | ID | A1 | A2 | REF_B | REF_C |
    |------------------------------|
    | 1  | a1 | a1 |  1    |   1   |
    | 2  | a2 | a2 |  2    |   1   |
    | 3  | a3 | a3 |  1    |   1   |
    |------------------------------|

> select * from table1_b;
    |--------------|
    | ID | B1 | B2 |
    |--------------|
    | 1  | b1 | b1 |
    | 2  | b2 | b2 |
    |--------------|

> select * from table1_c;
    |--------------|
    | ID | C1 | C2 |
    |--------------|
    | 1  | c1 | c1 |
    |--------------|
```

`table1` will be a updatable view over the join of these three tables.

- Do you see any possible flaw in this approach?
- Is there an easier solution?
- What are the possible restrictions we may have on the new `table1`. `table1` directly maps to an ADF Entity Object.

Answer (score 0):

Use a trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER upd_table1
BEFORE UPDATE OF a1
    OR UPDATE OF a2
    ON TABLE1
REFERENCING new AS new
BEGIN
   UPDATE table1
      SET b1 = new.a1, b2 = new.a2
    WHERE refb = new.id;
   UPDATE table1
      SET c1 = new.a1, c2 = new.a2
    WHERE refc = new.id;
END;
```

Comment: I am new to triggers, and Sql in general, so I could be wrong but it seems you are assuming that tuples 2 and 3 already exist and then we are inserting tuple 1. But in my scenario, tuple 1 will always be present much before the referencing tuples are inserted. Furthermore, this is a simplified case. My table has more than three `A` attributes.

Comment: Even if I handle the data replication manually while inserting rows for tuple 2 and 3, it still leaves out more issues. For tuple 1 any attribute could be updated. We cannot have trigger for all since attribute group `C` actually runs into hundreds. Furthermore copying hundreds of attributes into dummy row is not efficient.

Comment: I am not sure that I understood your question then. Having the column names and the column contents being equal in your question messes things up.

Comment: Oops. Sorry, but I could not think of anything else. Please do not related column content with column's name. `B1` is as equal to `b1` as 1 = 2. :) But `b1` is definitely equal to `b1` in other rows.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your proposed solution is a normalization of your original table, assuming you make REF_A & REF_B (though I'd name these A_ID and B_ID, myself) foreign keys to table1_b and table1_c. Is that what you have in mind?

One thing that's not clear to me is why you need two columns here (A1 & A2) if they contain the same data. Couldn't you consolidate that into a single column and then simply select twice if you need two copies in the result? ie, assuming you had only one "A" column instead of A1/A2:

```
select A, A from table1....
```

But, I might be missing the intended use case here.

I've never used ADF, but the oracle documentation seems to imply you can reference a view:

> Entity objects map to single objects in the datasource. In the vast majority of cases, these >are tables, views, synonyms, or snapshots in a database.

If this isn't very helpful, perhaps add some detail concerning the underlying purpose of this table.